# Flutter wearOS Round Watch Widget alignment

Tags: android, flutter, wear-os

Hello I would like to have three bottons at the end of my screen. What works for a rectangular clock as follows.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Text('test'),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green, // <-- Button color
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white, // <-- Splash color
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green, // <-- Button color
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white, // <-- Splash color
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green, // <-- Button color
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white, // <-- Splash color
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
```

[image]

But when I have a round clock the buttons are no longer completely in the picture. How can I guarantee that the buttons are completely visible?

Comment: try to wrap `Scaffold` with `SafeArea`?

Comment: Tryied with: ```Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child:  Stack(...``` same result

Comment: Recompiled the app. Same result.

Comment: didnt test it. also you can play with `alignment:Alingment(0,.7)` == .7

Comment: This works, but feels like a quick fix. I would like to use something like the Safeara